# Link to specific slide of jQuery-tools scrollable

Tags: javascript, url-routing, jquery-tools, scrollable

jQuery tools seems to have support for this built into the Tabs object, but not scrollable.

I want to be able to link to a specific slide on the following scrollable:
http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/5UWsr/

I'm using

```
if (location.hash)
{
    $('#' + location.hash.substring(1)).click();
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. It picks up the hashtag fine, but the click event is either not firing or not firing on the correct element.

Could you help me with how to mimic a click on an element to navigate to the correct slide? or some other way of getting this to work?

I am worried I'll get weird scrolling down the page to the anchor name, but will worry about that only if it does actually happen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to deeplink so that scrollable will scroll to a certain slide based on GET URL? here's what I do:

```
scrollapi = $("#scrollableID").data("scrollable");
deeplink = window.location.search.substring(1)
if (deeplink) {
    scrollapi.seekTo(deeplink);
}
```

Add the GET string is just the number of the slide you want to link to. (starts at 0)